# Export list of numbers as one column in a specified number format

Tags: export, output-formatting, list-manipulation

I am going to export some random lists as

```
Do[

  list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10}];

   Export["list-" <> ToString[i] <> "-" <> ToString[i + 2] <> ".txt", 
   list, "Table"];

   , {i, 1, 10}]
```

The results are as text files with the below format:

for example:

```
(*list-1-3.txt*)
0.7100544619837812
0.3608062869744495
0.22621774273894735
0.042131840502054985
0.6161812724281575
0.6822336053507754
0.8872971244858767
0.9205321314901684
0.5655929551228038
0.5759357721490808
```

**One** column that in each row of that there are many digits. I wish to have **One** column but less digits: For example:

```
(*list-1-3.txt*)
0.710054
0.360806
0.226217
0.042131
0.616181
0.682233
0.887297
0.920532
0.565592
0.575935
```

I used

```
Do[

  list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10}];

   Export["list-" <> ToString[i] <> "-" <> ToString[i + 2] <> ".txt", 
   NumberForm[list, 6], "Table"];

   , {i, 1, 10}]
```

But the results are as

```
{0.191954, 0.417033, 0.2569, 0.0891225, 0.242713, 0.614377, 0.32336,   0.803816, 0.24045, 0.741295}
```

These results are not desired they should be as a one column and without `{}`. I tried `Transpose` but it did not work correctly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paths =
  Table[
   FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", 
     "list-" <> ToString[i] <> "-" <> ToString[i + 2] <> ".txt"}],
   {i, 2}];
```

Make the files.

```
SeedRandom[42];
Do[
  list = RandomReal[{-1, 1} {10}];
  Export[
    paths[[i]], 
    (NumberForm[#, {5, 4}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}] // ToString) & /@ list], 
  {i, 2}]
```

Read in the files and display them.

```
Multicolumn[Import /@ paths, Frame -> All]
```

[image: files]

What should be noted here is

- `NumberForm` is a wrapper that must be supplied to each number individually.
- The `NumberForm` wrapped items must be converted strings before exporting.
- Reading back the files as done above brings the contents of each file as a string in which strings representing the numbers are separated by newling characters (`\n`)

Comment: I am so grateful of you for your answer, BUT recently I have noticed that there has remained a problem: `NumberForm[0.00123456 , 4]=0.001234` and `NumberForm[0.123456 , 4]=0.1234`. The last case is desired but for the first one I wish to have : `0.0012`, I think the `NumberForm` is not a correct function we are searching

Comment: @Irreversible. I have fixed a typo in the code for making the files. Perhaps that will clear up the problem.

Comment: I had noticed that problem it was about `path`. But I did not have a problem with that. I have a problem with NumberForm. The @andre asnswer does not have the problem but it has a problem with minus numbers. For example with RandomReal[{-1,1}]!!!!

Comment: @Irreversible. I have changed the number specification to `{6, 4}`. I think it will give you what you want.

Comment: @Irreversible. Made another change to address negative number issue.

Comment: I think we can use `Precision`

Comment: @Irreversible. `Precision` is for reporting the precision of inexact numbers for algorithm control and validation. It is not an output formatting tool.